# How do I make an element disappear after a set amount of time?

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to make the element with ID thanks1 disappear after a set amount of time. So far I have tried many things like setTimeout but none have worked

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="scripts.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> 1 </h1>
    <p>  QUESTION </p>
    <button onclick="rightAnswer()" id="a"> PLACE HOLDER </button>
    <button onclick="wrongAnswer()"> PLACE HOLDER </button>
    <p id="output"> </p>
    <p id="thanks1"> Well Done </p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a quiz and it gets you to the next page when you get a question correct, I tried putting a timeout in the rightAnswer function so as soon as you load 1.html the

Well Done

disappears after some time.

```
const wrong = "Wrong, try again!";
function wrongAnswer() {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = wrong
} 
function rightAnswer() {
    
    if (document.getElementById('a')) {
        location.href = "1.html";
        setTimeout(document.getElementById('thanks1').style.display = "none", 3000)
    }
    if (document.getElementById('b')) {
        location.href = "2.html"        
    }
    if (document.getElementById('c')) {
        location.href = "3.html"        
    }
}
function goBack() {
    if (document.getElementById('b')) {
        location.href = "index.html"        
    }
    if (document.getElementById('c')) {
        location.href = "1.html"        
    }
    if (document.getElementById('d')) {
        location.href = "2.html"        
    }
}
```

I wanted to make the element with the ID "thanks1" disappear once its corresponding page has loaded and after a set amount of time. I tried using setTimeout but nothing that I wanted seemed to happen.

Comment: `setTimeout` expects a function as its first parameter. You're currently passing an assignment.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I have just tried that and still the problem persists. : (

Comment: I think you have a misconception about how your code should work. Aside from the malformed `setTimeout`, you expect that the `setTimeout` runs **after** navigating to `1.html`. But when you navigate to a new page, the whole script is reset and won't continue where the previous page left off. You need to run the `setTimeout` immediately after the `1.html` page has been loaded, so not after someone clicks the button. Could you add the relevant parts of `1.html` so that we can help you with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect.
[MDN Docs: setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#examples)

From the docs:

> The global **setTimeout()** method sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.

```
setTimeout(functionRef, delay)
// Parameters
// functionRef - A **function** to be executed after the timer expires.
// delay - The time, in milliseconds that the timer should wait before 
// the specified function or code is executed.
```

For simplicity, I used the same 'thanks1' container for outputting the values

```
function wrongAnswer() {
// "wrong" should be a string unless you're calling a variable
  document.getElementById('thanks1').innerHTML = "wrong";
}

function rightAnswer() {    
  if (document.getElementById('a')) {
      location.href = "1.html";
      setTimeout(wrongAnswer, 3000)
  }
  ...
}
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/carbonspace/pen/QWxwvRo